# How to inject the Firebase messaging isHeadless prop into AppDelegate.mm file with react-native 0.69.1

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

System Information:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 97.44 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.16.0 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.07.04.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
    react-native: 0.69.1 => 0.69.1
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Hello folks, I am working on a react-native 0.69.1 project that uses Firebase push-notification service. I confirm that I am successfully getting push notifications when the app is in the foreground, background and in a killed state. In order to correctly update my badge count when receiving a push notification outside the app, I need to add to index.js the firebase method setBackgroundMessageHandler and handle if the app was opened via isHeadless prop.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  //Update badge count in here
});

function HeadlessCheck({isHeadless}) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return App;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

I am aware that the headless prop does not exist on iOS and needs to be injected into AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.mm file. However firebase has not updated their documentation to inject the isHeadless prop into the AppDelegate.mm file created by react-native-0.69.1.

Below is the snipped of my AppDelegate.mm file where I have to inject the isHeadless prop in.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNBootSplash.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <TSBackgroundFetch/TSBackgroundFetch.h>

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>

static NSString *const kRNConcurrentRoot = @"concurrentRoot";

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTCxxBridgeDelegate, RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate> {
  RCTTurboModuleManager *_turboModuleManager;
  RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *_bridgeAdapter;
  std::shared_ptr<const facebook::react::ReactNativeConfig> _reactNativeConfig;
  facebook::react::ContextContainer::Shared _contextContainer;
}
@end
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  
  [FIRApp configure];
  
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
  _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();
  _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);
  _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc] initWithBridge:bridge contextContainer:_contextContainer];
  bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
#endif

  NSDictionary *initProps = [self prepareInitialProps];
  UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"amigo", initProps);

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
   center.delegate = self;
  
  // [REQUIRED] Register BackgroundFetch
  [[TSBackgroundFetch sharedInstance] didFinishLaunching];
  
  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];
  
  return YES;
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}



/// This method controls whether the `concurrentRoot`feature of React18 is turned on or off.
///
/// @see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
/// @note: This requires to be rendering on Fabric (i.e. on the New Architecture).
/// @return: `true` if the `concurrentRoot` feture is enabled. Otherwise, it returns `false`.
- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  // Switch this bool to turn on and off the concurrent root
  return true;
}

- (NSDictionary *)prepareInitialProps
{
  NSMutableDictionary *initProps = [NSMutableDictionary new];

#ifdef RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  initProps[kRNConcurrentRoot] = @([self concurrentRootEnabled]);
#endif

  return initProps;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

- (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  _turboModuleManager = [[RCTTurboModuleManager alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                             delegate:self
                                                            jsInvoker:bridge.jsCallInvoker];
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultJsExecutorFactory(bridge, _turboModuleManager);
}

#pragma mark RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate

- (Class)getModuleClassFromName:(const char *)name
{
  return RCTCoreModulesClassProvider(name);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                      jsInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::CallInvoker>)jsInvoker
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                     initParams:
                                                         (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (id<RCTTurboModule>)getModuleInstanceFromClass:(Class)moduleClass
{
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultModuleFromClass(moduleClass);
}

#endif

@end
```

RN Community , please help me out if you experience the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change this

```
UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"amigo", initProps);
```

to

```
NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
NSMutableDictionary *initialProps = [initProps mutableCopy];
[initialProps addEntriesFromDictionary:appProperties];
  
UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"amigo", initialProps);
```